# why aren't both labels updated?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter

class Store1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.variable1 = Tkinter.IntVar()

    def add(self):
        counter1 = self.variable
        counter1.set(counter1.get() + 1)
        counter2 = self.variable1
        counter2.set(counter2.get() + 1)
        return counter1.get(), counter2.get()

class Main(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        counter1 = Store1()
        counter2 = Store1()


        self.label  = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=counter1.variable)
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self, command=lambda:counter1.add(), text='+1')
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

        self.label1  = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=counter2.variable1)
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, command=lambda:counter2.add(), text='+1')
        self.label1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()




root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean, when you press either button, both variables should be updated?

Comment: This works as I would expect it to.

Comment: Yes I'm new to python, both variables should update but they don't :(

Comment: Help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'll get you some code below. Hold on a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function that calls both of the counters to add.

```
import Tkinter

class Store1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.variable1 = Tkinter.IntVar()

    def add(self):
        counter1 = self.variable
        counter1.set(counter1.get() + 1)
        counter2 = self.variable1
        counter2.set(counter2.get() + 1)
        return counter1.get(), counter2.get()

class Main(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        counter1 = Store1()
        counter2 = Store1()

        def both_counters():
            counter1.add()
            counter2.add()

        self.label  = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=counter1.variable)
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self, command=both_counters, text='+1')
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

        self.label1  = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=counter2.variable1)
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, command=both_counters, text='+1')
        self.label1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that it is better for you to set the counters as attributes so that you don't have to nest functions.

Comment: okay thankyou, I was on the right tracks when trying to fix. i did the same as you but but i kept lambda in the command. thankyou so much.

Comment: i was on the right tracks in fixing it, i created the function but used lambda in in the command. thankyou so much